# Trying to add two URLs together to get one URL

Tags: python-3.x, url, join

How can I get I an absolute URL from an absolute URL and a relative URL? The relative URL comes from the `href` of a link.

This what I tried:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mainurl = "http://www.bestbuy.ca"
theurl = "http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/category/top-freezer-      refrigerators/34734.aspx?type=product&page=1&pageSize=96"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

producturl = soup.find('h4',{"class":"prod-title"}).find('a')

print (producturl)

fullurl = (mainurl,producturl)

print(fullurl)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `mainurl` and `producturl` since this seems to be a task of string concatenation and not specific to URLs.

Comment: The output comes out as Insignia "('http://www.bestbuy.ca', 'Insignia 30" 18 Cu. Ft. Top Freezer Refrigerator (NS-RTM18WH7-C) - White')"  I need the whole thing to come together as one.  The main url is "http://www.bestbuy.ca and the product url is based on the URL found in the class-title.

Comment: mainurl is given: "http://www.bestbuy.ca" and producturl is a soup object: <a href="/en-CA/product/insignia-insignia-30-18-cu-ft-top-freezer-refrigerator-ns-rtm18wh7-c-white-ns-rtm18wh7-c/10405330.aspx?path=f01747c36745ca8e40165050c79ecc16en02">Insignia 30" 18 Cu. Ft. Top Freezer Refrigerator (NS-RTM18WH7-C) - White</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ['href'] on beautifulsoup object to get the link as a string. Then just concatanate.

```
fullurl = mainurl + soup.find('h4',{"class":"prod-title"}).find('a')['href']
```

or

```
fullurl = mainurl + producturl['href']
```

Answer (score 1):

As @keiv.fly already posted, you need to get the `href` [attribute value](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) of a link. Then, *instead of regular string concatenation*, use [`.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to combine the base url with the relative URL of the link to produce an absolute URL.

I would also improve the way you are locating the link:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

product_url = soup.select_one('h4.prod-title a')["href"]
product_url = urljoin(mainurl, product_url)
```